# where's socketTextStream in pyflink

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I want to translate the following code into pyflink and run it in pyflink-shell.sh afterwards.

```
public class MapDemo {
    private static int index = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //1.获取执行环境配置信息
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        //2.定义加载或创建数据源（source）,监听9000端口的socket消息
        DataStream<String> textStream = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000, "\n");
        //3.map操作。
        DataStream<String> result = textStream.map(s -> (index++) + ".您输入的是：" + s);
        //4.打印输出sink
        result.print();
        //5.开始执行
        env.execute();
    }
```

But I can not found `socketTextStream`in `b_env`,`bt_env`,`s_env`,`st_env`

so where's the `socketTextStream` in pyflink api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Flink 1.12, out-of-the-box PyFlink appears to only support these connectors:

- FlinkKafkaConsumer
- FlinkKafkaProducer
- JdbcSink
- StreamingFileSink

See https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-python/pyflink/datastream/connectors.py.

Because `socketTextStream` cannot support exactly-once semantics, its use is generally discouraged, and it wasn't included in PyFlink.

Comment: Is this still the case? I'm seeing a Python DataStream API.

Comment: That's true, and I've updated my answer. But I believe `socketTextStream` is still not available.

Comment: Yeah I looked into the mailing list threads and the socket stream isn't being implemented (at least for now) for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `socketTextStream` in pyflink, though it has not been officially supported yet. Example:

```
from pyflink.datastream import DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s_env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    socket_stream = DataStream(s_env._j_stream_execution_environment.socketTextStream('localhost', 9999))
    socket_stream.print()
    s_env.execute('socket_stream')
```